# Making bots join/leave a discord channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So Ive been working on a program to make my bots join a discord channel but i keep running into errors this is the code`case "music":
            message.member.voiceChannel.join();`

Comment: Please post the complete code and the error's you're getting

Comment: `bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {

        case "music":
            message.member.voiceChannel.join();
    }


});`

Comment: error is too big

Comment: but it says about ffmpeg yet its just to join the channel not play music

Comment: Try to restructure the question in your question with as much information as possible. Right now it's really difficult to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment, you said that the error was about FFMPEG. To get a Discord bot to join a channel and play anything, you need FFMPEG do audio related things. Are you self-hosting? If you are, you need to install FFMPEG on your machine and insure the executable for the application(FFMPEG) is on your machines PATH system variables.